# Avoiding silicone watch strap breakage

Tags: technology

I have this old (and dear) simple digital wrist watch (a [Casio W71](http://www.digital-watch.com/DWL/1work/casio-w-71/)). It uses a Silicone [strap](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1U9ivRXXXXXaQaXXXq6xXFXXXC/16mm-font-b-18mm-b-font-20mm-font-b-Silicone-b-font-font-b-Watch-b.jpg) by default - and (one side of) this strap tends to tear at the point where you fasten it, after a few years of use.

I was wondering if it's feasible, for someone who's not much of a craftsman, to either:

1. Prevent the (side-of-a-)strap from tearing, or
2. Fashion a strap or one side of a strap for the watch which would last longer, or would be easy to fix (e.g. by sewing).

Comment: Why not just accept they don't last long after being in contact with oil and sweat constantly and buy a new one when it breaks? They aren't expensive. Or change to a nylon or leather strap? I did just that with my OG Pebble as one of the silicon bands perished after years of abuse

Comment: @MrPablo: 1. Goes against the spirt of this site? 2. I don't mind buying a new strap, except that where I live, they're massively overpriced (10 EUR per piece). I couldn't find someplace cheap. I'll probably try buying online, but that takes a lot of time to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Velcro once it breaks cut the excess off and replace it with Velcro straps instead and sew them on to be able to be used.

Comment: You can actually buy velcro watch straps. I did exactly this with a treasured Casio myself and the velcro one lasted much longer than the original resin one.

Answer (score 0):

If Silicone strap is broken, you can do one magic with the rubber band.

- Wind the rubber band around strap so as to join two broken pieces(it would be a better option if you do this trick as and when it is broken and starts to be apart into two).
- Burn the joint using a candle or cigarette lighter until the rubber band fuses with strap. Take care when you do this, as rubber can provide some black smoke.
- After fusing with strap, keep the strap on ice so as to reduce its temperature.
- Use a blade to chisel out extra protruded parts during fusion so that it won't cause irritation while you wear it.

> Note: Please select a rubber band that matches the color of your strap. If your strap has light color, the result of using this trick may leave some dark marks around the surface, which I suggest you can take as an art.